# how to replace multiple substrings in column names using a dictionary in pandas?

Tags: python

I want to replace parts of string in columns using a dictionary. The current line I made runs without errors but doesn't replace any of the text I want it to replace and I'm guessing its to do with the commands only applying specifically to columns with words mentioned in the dictionary.

Here is the code:

```
df2.rename(columns = {
    "I'm" : "I am",
    "this company" : "Company",
    "â€™" : "'",
    "Iâ€™m" : "'"}, axis = 'columns', inplace = True)
```

examples of what the columns have that I wish to change are:

I feel like **I'm** valued as a person at this company .

To:

I feel like **I am** valued as a person at Company .

I get enough feedback to understand if **Iâ€™m** doing my job well .

To:

I get enough feedback to understand if **I'm** doing my job well .

Also, since the text **Iâ€™m** is being converted to **I'm** could the corrected version of this code then convert it to **I am**?

Dataframe:

```
Columns: [I understand how my job contributes to the overall success of this company .  I get enough feedback to understand if Iâ€™m doing my job well .    I feel that Iâ€™m growing professionally .  Whatâ€™s on your mind right now that youâ€™d like to tell us?.  I'm satisfied with the amount of flexibility I have in my work schedule .]
```

Comment: You're currently renaming the columns, not replacing the substrings inside the columns.

Comment: also please add a sample of your dataframe

Comment: Hi, I've added a sample dataframe

Comment: I figured it out! I shall post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To replace substring inside columns and not replace the whole colum, the .`replace` notation is required:

```
'create dict of common words inconsistently used that ask the same questions in a survey every quarter'
inconsistencyfixerdict = {
    "I'm" : "I am",
    "this company" : "Company",
    "â€™" : "'",
    "Iâ€™m" : "'"}
inconsistencyfixerdict = dict(inconsistencyfixerdict)
print(inconsistencyfixerdict)
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().replace(inconsistencyfixerdict, regex=True)
```